# How do you run scrapyrt with forever.js or pm2?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, scrapy, pm2, forever

I moved a project to a live server and now I need something like pm2 or forever.js to run [`scrapyrt`](https://pypi.org/project/scrapyrt/).

However, neither command seemed to work...

**forever.js**

I ran this command which failed (and I was in an active virtual environment):

```
# forever start scrapyrt -p 5003
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: scrapyrt
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /root/my-scrapy-project/scrapyrt does not exist.
```

**pm2**

```
# pm2 start scrapyrt -p 5003
# pm2 list
┌─────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name        │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ scrapyrt    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 15   │ errored   │ 0%       │ 0b       │ root     │ disabled │
└─────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

How do you set scrapyrt to permanently be turned on and automatically restarted like with `pm2` or `forever`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if the server IP address is `65.124.80.15` and I want to run scrapyrt on port `5003` off it, I can use the following commands to get `pm2` running `scrapyrt`...

```
cd <into_scrapy_projectfile_containing_scrapy.cfg_file>
pm2 start "scrapyrt -p 5003 -i 65.124.80.15"
```

Comment: Later, I found this also works too: `pm2 start scrapyrt --name scrapyrt --max-memory-restart 100M --no-autorestart -- -p 5008 -i "65.124.80.15"`